# Is OAuth 2.0 a Framework or Protocol?

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth

I just received a requirement to apply Oauth2.0 authentication on REST APIs on SSO (Centralized Users Database/Server).

I am totally new to OAuth2.0. Just learning concepts through out the internet.

I got pretty good idea of how OAuth2.0 works.
All the concepts of Access Bearer Tokens & Refresh Tokens.

The one thing which still bugs me is that:

**Is it a framework or a Protocol?**

I mean is it some sort of standard or set of instructions to be followed for authentication?

In my case I don't care about Login with Facebook or Google.

All I need is to login users and get Access & Refresh Tokens, and authenticate user based routes using Access Bearer Tokens.

Since I have been studying official OAuth2.0 documentations for Node.js:

https://oauth2-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

All it says is to create a model for inserting, fetching, validating tokens.

A custom logic to handle all this.

If it was a framework, it would have handled everything by itself, but as far as I can see that it doesn't offer much to a developer. I cant see any built-in functions or methods in the documentations. e.g Generate Access Token, Get Access Token, Refresh Token etc. All this is based on a custom logic.

I am still in the search for simple Oauth2 Nodejs official library that can authenticate routes by calling simple methods.

Because if thats not the case with Oauth2 and I really have to manage all the logic custom way, then why shouldn't I use JWT?

Am I not getting this? Can anyone help me a bit in figuring out this confusion?

Comment: OAuth2 is not a framework in the 'web framework' sense. The project you linked is just 1 oauth2 implementation for Node.js. Here's another: https://github.com/curveball/a12n-server . So even if OAuth2 is a 'framework for authentication systems', it's a bit unrelated to what exactly that specific Node.js implementation offers or doesn't.

Comment: @Evert Actually Oauth2 is giving me hard time, even though i learned all of its concepts but I still couldn't find any good and simple Oauth2 official Library for nodejs.

Comment: All I went through so far is custom handling and management of tokens, So why not use JWT instead?

Comment: There is no official library for OAuth2. JWT and OAuth2 solve very different things and can both be used at the same time.

Comment: Why is it NodeJS related? I couldn't find the question/answer because of the `nodejs` tag. Please, consider removing the tag.

Comment: nodejs tag removed

Answer (score 0):

It is a protocol, since it defines how multiple parties exchange messages to delegate authorization to manipulate resources behind an API to an application called a client. It is defined by an IETF standard Request For Comment (RFC) document here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

It is also a framework, since it let's implementers extend the protocol with other grants. OpenID Connect is the OAuth2 extension that deals with authentication and is defined here: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

Comment: I disagree with this OAuth 2.0 by itself is not a protocol is a framework. A protocol would be more specific and OAuth 2.0 leaves a lot of things up to the different parties involved. From the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.8

Comment: @OmarDonnadieuMercado One does not exclude the other. As I said in my answer, OAuth2 is both a protocol and framework. It describes how parties interact, which is exactly what a protocol does. See also https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.2, which described the protocol flow.